# Is there any Electric Current on (Solar) Coronal Loops?

Tags: astrophysics, solar-system, plasma-physics, stellar-physics

I'm studying Plasma Astrophysics and now I have came across the following problem, which I have been trying to solve on my own, and came to a "non-logical" conclusion?

Here is the Problem:

Let the Coronal Loop have the following Magnetic Field:

$$ B_{x} = B_o e^{-kz}cos(kx)$$ and $$ B_z = -B_o e^{-kz}sin(kx) $$
for z>0 , and |x| < pi/2k

After finding the Magnetic field lines, it says find the Current and Density distribution on z dependence.

From $ J = \bigtriangledown x B$

One can find that $J=0$ ??

From Equilibrium Equation the Density has no dependence on z , except the gravitational field, which is weak?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One can find that J=0 ??

Your math is okay.  What you are being asked to examine is a special case of a [coronal loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_loop) constructed from what is called a [*potential field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_magnetic_field).  You often see the converse, namely a *non-potential field*, in discussions of [dynamo theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory).

It is perfectly fine, mathematically, to have $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = 0$.  Whether that describes reality is another issue but it is okay mathematically.  One of the consequences is that this geometry describes a [*force-free field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-free_magnetic_field), i.e., one that satisfies $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} = 0$.

A general force-free field is defined by assuming:
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \alpha \left( \mathbf{r} \right) \ \mathbf{B}
$$
where $\alpha \left( \mathbf{r} \right)$ is a scalar function of position/altitude.  Under these assumptions, a potential field is the limit where $\alpha \left( \mathbf{r} \right) \rightarrow 0$ while the non-potential field corresponds to $\alpha \left( \mathbf{r} \right) \neq 0$.  Using vector calculus and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$, one can show that:
$$
\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla \ \alpha \left( \mathbf{r} \right) = 0
$$

> From Equilibrium Equation the Density has no dependence on z , except the gravitational field, which is weak?  Any help?

Under these conditions, one can describe the number density and pressure using hydrodynamics, similar to how one examines neutral atmospheres, i.e.:
$$
n\left( r \right) \propto e^{-r/h}
$$
where $h$ is the characteristic [scale height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height) and $r$ is the altitude.

## **Side Note**

While I have not seen your specific example used, I have seen something similar given by:
$$
\begin{align}
  B_{x} & = B_{o} \ e^{- l \ z} \ \sin{\left( k x \right)} \\
  B_{y} & = B_{o} \ e^{- l \ z} \ \sin{\left( k x \right)} \\
  B_{z} & = B_{o} \ e^{- l \ z} \ \cos{\left( k x \right)} \\
\end{align}
$$
which has $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} \neq 0$.  As you probably already noticed, if you change the sign of your z-component from your example you would also have $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} \neq 0$.

Comment: Since my scalar function is $$a(\textbf{r}) = 0$$  Using the following equation: $$ \nabla P - \rho \textbf{z} = 0 $$ and since  $$ P = nk_bT$$ -my approximation is T(x,y,z) = Const  -  I don't get the exponential you have.

Comment: *Couldnt edit my previous comment:

I get the result $$ \rho = \rho_o e^{-mgz/kT}$$

Comment: @BillyMatlock - That's fine.  In this case the scale height is just $h = kT/mg$ and $\rho = \bar{m} \ n$, where $\bar{m}$ is the mean mass of the gas (i.e., roughly the ion mass here).